# iOS retain count issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, retaincount

this is part of my code:

```
NSMutableArray oldWordsArray;

newWordsArray= [self getNewWordArray];

-(NSMutableArray *) getOldWordArray{

    NSString *user_id = (NSString*)[tool readObkect:@"user_id"];

    NSMutableArray oldWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    oldWords = [database getOldWord:user_id];
    NSLog(@"从所有词库中得到新单词");
    return oldWords;
}`
```

So: how should I release Variable `oldWordsArray` and `oldWords`, many thanks!

Comment: you must use ARC, instead of manually releasing the objects.

Comment: Just so you know `IOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS) is not the same as `iOS` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) edited your title.

Comment: `you must use ARC, instead of manually releasing the objects.`You actually don't. You can use one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing, that you are not using ARC. This:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getOldWordArray{
    NSString *user_id = (NSString*)[tool readObkect:@"user_id"];

    NSMutableArray oldWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    oldWords = [database getOldWord:user_id];
    NSLog(@"从所有词库中得到新单词");
    return oldWords;
}
```

Can be translated into this:

```
-(NSArray *) getOldWordArray{
    NSString *user_id = (NSString*)[tool readObkect:@"user_id"];
    NSArray oldWords = [database getOldWord:user_id];
    NSLog(@"从所有词库中得到新单词");
    return oldWords;
}
```

And then:

```
- (NSArray *)oldWordArray
{
   NSString *user_id = (NSString*)[tool readObkect:@"user_id"];
   return [database getOldWord:user_id];
}
```

I am not sure what the `database` is, but it should return an `autoreleased` object, so you don't have to `release` it yourself, in that context. You should as well, not use the prefix `get` in `getOldWord`. You can as well, use an `NSArray` instead of a `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

So much discussions are here regarding this 
 First thing You should check that if ARC enabled if yes then you don't worry about releasing it will done by ARC itself

if not then use the code like this

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getOldWordArray{

    NSString *user_id = (NSString*)[tool readObkect:@"user_id"];

    NSMutableArray oldWords = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    oldWords = [database getOldWord:user_id];
    NSLog(@"从所有词库中得到新单词");
    return oldWords ;
}
```

or you can use

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getOldWordArray{

    NSString *user_id = (NSString*)[tool readObkect:@"user_id"];

    NSLog(@"从所有词库中得到新单词");
    return [database getOldWord:user_id];
}
```